# Makefile excluding files

Tags: file, makefile, substring

I am creating a GNU Makefile and I have a following problem:

I have a list of exclude files (and directories) that need to be excluded from source list.
Now, removing listed files from list isn't to big of a problem. I just do the following:

```
NEWSRC := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c')
EXCLUDES := $(shell cat ./$(TARGET12)_exclude.txt) #TARGET12 is a Makefile parameter
CSRC := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDES),$(NEWSRC))
```

The problem is when EXCLUDES contain directory (not the file name), and all the file names under the same directory should be also excluded. For example, if the one member of EXCLUDES variable is ../sources/filesystem/SomePath, then all the files under that directory should be excluded from CSRC also. For example, those files could be:

```
../sources/filesystem/SomePath/something.c
../sources/filesystem/SomePath/src/something.c
../sources/filesystem/SomePath/Some1/src/something.c
```

Do you know how this could be solved inside Makefile?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the elements in `NEWSRC` necessarily start with
`../sources/filesystem/SomePath`, how about adding suffix to `EXCLUDES` as
the following?

```
$(filter-out $(addsuffix /%,$(EXCLUDES)),$(NEWSRC))
```

Comment: I'm confused by the slash in `/%`. I can see how it works for the directories, but wouldn't this prevent the files in `$(EXCLUDES)` from being filtered out?

Comment: @eriktous: Yes, you are right.
I suppose the above code will be used in combination with OP's code.

Comment: You can handle both cases if instead of `$(addsuffix ...)` you add `/%` only for directories: `$(foreach i,$(EXCLUDES),$(if $(wildcard $i/.),$i/%,$i))`

Comment: @Idelic:
Interesting solution! As of this writing, OP seems not to have accepted
an answer yet. How about posting it as your answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to modify the `..._exclude.txt` files, you could use patterns.

foo.exclude.txt:

```
badFile.cc anotherBadFile.cc \
../sources/filesystem/SomePath/% \
yetAnotherBadFile.cc
```

Just slap a '%' on the end of every directory you want to exclude.

If you're *not* allowed to modify `foo_exclude.txt`, you can do the same thing within the makefile, but it's kind of ugly:

```
EXCLUDES := $(shell cat ./$(TARGET12)_exclude.txt | sed -e 's|\/ |\/% |' -e 's|\/$$|\/%|')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
EXCLUDES := $(shell cat ./$(TARGET12)_exclude.txt)
EXCLUDES_FILE := { notdir $(EXCLUDES )}
CSRC := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDES_FILE),$(NEWSRC))
```

Let me know if it works